# CMake: How to specify v14.13 toolset (Side-by-side minor version)

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I am trying to compile OpenCV with Cuda 9.2 enabled, and after a little bit of googling I noticed that I need to use v14.13 toolset. Therefore I installed v14.13 toolset:

[image]

Now I have both v14.13 and v14.15 toolsets installed.

However I could not figure out what parameter I should give to CMake in order to use v14.13. I googled for some time to find a documentation however I failed.

If I use -t v141, then I get the v14.15 toolset:

[image]

What should I do to get v14.13 toolset?

Note: I checked this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/11/15/side-by-side-minor-version-msvc-toolsets-in-visual-studio-2017/) and will continue build with the instructions explained there. However I am still curious if there is a way to directly do it from cmake.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass -T version=14.13.

See [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET.html#variable:CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET).